# Ubuntu mysterious proxy

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, proxy, system-administration

Can't find where my proxy settings are stored.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. Once upon a time I created a "manual" proxy through Network app GUI.
Turned it off same way but now I everytime I use **shell** I have to "empty" proxies with `export http_proxy=""` and so on.

It's there.

```
env | grep proxy
```

- http_proxy=http://proxy1.bsu:3128/
- https_proxy=https://proxy1.bsu:3128/

Proxy is up but where?

- **/etc/environment** - not there
- **/etc/apt/apt.conf** - not there
- **/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ folder** - not there
- **/etc/profile** - not there
- **/etc/bash.bashrc** - not there
- **~/.bashrc** - not there
- **~/.profile** - not there
- **~/.bash_profile** - not there
- **~/.bash_login** - not there
- **~/.pam_environment** - not there

Ran `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'` with no effect.
Tried through `gconf-editor \ dconf-editor` still no luck. I tried to update system with `apt-get update` too. Logged out and in, restarted shell sessions, etc.

It's more like superuser q, but still.

Comment: Now it sucks even more because Sublime's Package Manager plugin uses these mysterious proxies, can't update a thing (

Comment: Have you tried to bruteforce it like: grep -r "http://proxy1.bsu:3128" / (but not formatted as link)

Comment: have you looked at /etc/NetworkManager/ or /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d ?

Comment: @hovanessyan I thought about that, just worried that it'll take huge amount of time. I'll give it a try anyway. Wanted a more elegant solution )

Comment: This appears [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Comment: @EliahKagan Really? Thank you for your valuable input. As for being off-topic maybe you should check out Stack's Ubuntu & Linux tags.

Comment: @justartem Is this about coding or software development in any way? If not, it's off-topic. (As the FAQ explains.) The presence of other questions that are off-topic does not make this one on-topic. There are plenty of off-topic questions. People flag them, their flags get marked helpful, and they are slowly closed or migrated to other sites. The great majority of questions in those tags, by the way, *are* about software development.

Comment: @EliahKagan Too bad you're not a moderator, you would see that I flagged it 3 hours ago for transfer.

Comment: @justartem I'm glad you agree this doesn't belong here. :)

Comment: Did you try restarting terminal after changing the proxy settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even bruteforce method of `grep -rl proxy1.bsu /` didn't find any files. 
Had to override variables in `~/.bashrc`

Probably my system's bug.